# String concatenation in C

Tags: c, string, concatenation

So I got this function which is able to put a space infront of a "/" C if there is no space. And it cuts up the string fine but I get an error, possibly a memory violation when I try to concat the string together. Please give me a hand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* substr(const char *pstr, int start, int numchars) {
    char* pnew = malloc(numchars + 1);
    strncpy(pnew, pstr + start, numchars);
    pnew[numchars] = '\0';
    return pnew;
}

char* fixString(char str[]) {
    char* position;
    char* newString = "";
    char* finalString;

    int oldPosition = 0;
    printf("Original str: %s\n", str);
    printf("Original length: %d\n\n", strlen(str));

    position = strchr(str, '/');
    while (position != NULL) {
        int charPosition = position - str;

        printf("String position: %d->%d\n", oldPosition, charPosition);
        newString = substr(str, oldPosition, charPosition - oldPosition);
        oldPosition = charPosition;
        if (charPosition > 0 && str[charPosition - 1] != ' ') {
            printf("Previous char: %c\n", str[charPosition - 1]);
            newString = strcat(newString, " ");
        }

        printf("String: |%s|\n", newString);
        if (strlen(newString) > 0) {
            finalString[0] = strcat(finalString, newString);
        }
        printf("------------\n");
        position = strchr(position + 1, '/');
    }
    char* lastString = substr(str, oldPosition, strlen(str));
    finalString = strcat(finalString, lastString);
    printf("lastString: %s\n\n", lastString);
    return finalString;
}

int main() {
    char* testString = "/Filter /FlateDecode/Length 7108/Subtype /Type1C";
    printf("%s", fixString(testString));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase in the form of a question. Thanks.

Comment: You never `malloc` memory for your `newString` and `finalString`.

Comment: Question: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You never allocate a target buffer. The `finalString` variable isn't initialised to anything.

That's not the only problem with your code, either. You seem to be treating the `char *` as some kind of smart string type, but it is nothing more than a pointer into a memory location. For instance, this:

```
newString = strcat(newString, " ");
```

doesn't concatenate two strings and return the concatenated result. It appends a space onto the char buffer newString points to and returns the same buffer. Assigning to newString is harmless, but misleading.

```
// It is the callers responsibility to free the returned string.
char *fixString(char *str) {
    int len;
    char *s;
    char *dest;
    int after_space;

    // First pass, figure out the size of the output.
    len = 0;
    after_space = 0;
    for (s = str; *s; s++) {
        len += 1 + (!after_space && *s == '/');
        after_space = *s == ' ';
    }
    dest = malloc(len + 1);

    s = dest;
    after_space = 0;
    while(*str) {
        if (!after_space && *str == '/') *s++ = ' ';
        after_space = (*s++ = *str++) == ' ';
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I want to change all "/" with " /" if "/" dosen't already have a space in the char before.

Comment: @Thomas: Like I said, I didn't analyse your code in depth. The point is that you should first allocate a buffer, and then populate it by copying from the source string according to whatever logic you need. In this case, you will have to either allocate double the space, just in case every character in the source is a `/`, or do two passes, one to figure out how big the result buffer needs to be, and a second to do the actual transcription.

Comment: @Thomas: I've amended my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate some memory for `finalString`.

Try doing it like this:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
char* finalString = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
// ...
strncat(finalString, "something", 1024);
```

Remember to call `free()` on the pointer when you don't need it anymore (not in your function - after the function returns, somewhere in client code, whenever the result's not needed).

Answer (score 0):

You never `malloc` memory for your `newString` and `finalString` pointers. `strcat` expects that the destination pointer you give it has enough space to store the strings.

Comment: Well, I never had problems with newString in this regard. newString is malloc'ed for by substr, right?

Comment: @Thomas - that is true, `substr` will `malloc` a pointer for `newString`, except that that can also potentially be a problem because: a) you never `free` the pointer, b) you eventually try to `strcat` into `newString`, and `newString` isn't allocated enough space to store the resulting concatenated string.

Comment: I see, so in the while loop I should free newString between each run, correct?

Comment: @Thomas - you should `free` your allocated pointers when you are done with them. As your code is now, you could do `free` at the end of the `fixString` function. In the middle of your function you'll PROBABLY do a `realloc` on `newString`, too, and you do not have to `free` before calling `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also have to check for the size after malloc() and realloc() if necessary. Welcome to the beautiful world of memory management in C :)